# catch a SIGINT in python while the process on block read from a pipe

Tags: python, pipe, ipc

I have a python code when I read from pipe in blocking mode, when I click control + c and send SIGINT the process wont catch it. only after I send some data in pipe the SIGINT method is activated. how can I catch the SIGINT in mid read?
(the python code runs on Linux)
this is my read from pipe code

```
while(msg.find(EOM) == -1):
            print "cp1"
            char= cpp_to_python_pipe.read(1)
            print "cp2"
```

this is the SIGINT handler

```
def sigterm_handler(_signo, _stack_frame):
#get sigint signal and send event to the cpp
print "terminated by user signal(" +str(_signo) + ")"
send_event_to_cpp("<on_sigint>")
os._exit(0)
```